# Bootstrap tables not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap table, I'm not posting code because it's a straightforward table and it was working, but now it's showing in list form, not as a table anymore.  I re-linked my references to bootstrap, and the CSS file.  What am I missing?

Comment: Without posting code, it is impossible to help you. I use bootstrap every day and never had an issue with a bootstrap feature not working. So assuming I am correct, something is either wrong with your browser or your code. But since there is no code, I cannot help you diagnose.

Comment: I copied and pasted my table into your body, and it works.  I must have a misplaced <div> or something somewhere.

Comment: When I reference the bootstrap css file, it works, but when I reference the one I changed, it just lists the table down in one column.  The only thing I changed was colors, and I added some code for a slideshow.

Comment: I personally do not recommend changing the bootstrap css file.  Just create new styles for what you are trying to do and if they are declared after the bootstrap css file they will overwrite the bootstrap class.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean I downloaded a "theme" from bootswatch.com, and changed the colors in that file.  I'm not sure what I should refernce and where, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not posting code, I will. This works fine for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to post the code, it says it's too many characters.  I broke down every part and deleted sections, and it still is listing it one column down the page.  It looks good in Dreamweaver, but when I put it on the server, it's not making the table.  Is there something I need to put on the server besides the bootstrap folder?